# Как избежать multiple definition при определении массива в заголовочном файле?

Tags: c

У меня есть заголовочный файл, в котором определен массив структур.
Необходимо использовать этот массив в различных *.c файлах.

Однако, при подключении заголовочного файла к *.c, требующих этого, возникает multiple definition массива.

К сожалению, заголовочный файл менять не могу. Вносить изменения могу только в *.c файлы. Подскажите пожалуйста, что можно сделать, ничего не могу сообразить...

**UPD:** в заголовочном файле имеется

```
#ifndef NAME
#define NAME
...
#endif
```

Почему это не помогает?

**UPD:**

```
//header.h

#ifndef NAME
#define NAME

struct commands {
    int a;
    int b;
};

struct commands const array[] {
    {1, 2},
    {5, 6},
    {NULL, NULL}
};

#endif

//file1.c
#include header.h
int function(void) {
    sub_function(array);
}

//file1.c
#include header.h
int function2(void) {
    sub_function2(array);
}
```

Comment: В таком коде никак, поскольку file1 и file2 разные единицы компиляции. Вам надо выбрать какой-то один из них, где будет определен  `array[]`. Это можно сделать либо условной трансляцией с добавлением соответствующих макро-имен, либо (для Вас наверное проще) просто убрать `array[]` из .h и поместить его в один из .c файлов.

Comment: «К сожалению, заголовочный файл менять не могу» — проблема именно в заголовочном файле. Вам **придётся** его поменять. Можно, конечно, сделать какой-нибудь грубый хак, но это неправильный путь.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если Вам по какой-то причине действительно важно держать все в .h файле, то его можно модифицировать, например, так.

```
//header.h

#ifndef NAME
#define NAME

struct commands {
    int a;
    int b;
};

#ifdef MAKE_COMMANDS
struct commands const array[] = {
    {1, 2},
    {5, 6},
    {NULL, NULL}
};
#else
extern struct commands const array[];
#endif

#endif
```

Тогда только в одном из файлов перед `#include header.h` напишите `#define MAKE_COMMANDS` (или транслируйте его с -DMAKE_COMMANDS).

P.S.
присваивать переменным типа `int` `NULL` не самая правильная идея.

Comment: Прошу прощения, там не int, а указатели (просто суть показал).

Comment: Спасибо за идею, буду пробовать

Answer (score 1):

Без примера вашего кода могу предложить следующее. В заголовочном файле, перед определением массива структур добавить

```
extern ...;
```

a само определение перенести в соответствующий сишный файл.

Пример

Файл crc16.h:

```
...
extern const uint16_t crc16_table[];
...
```

Файл crc16.c:

```
const uint16_t crc16_table[] = {
...
};
```

**UPD:** Вот теперь, после появления реального кода можно сделать так:

```
struct commands const array[] = {
    {1, 2},
    {5, 6},
    {NULL, NULL}
};
```

перенесите в файл, ну например header.c, а в файле header.h замените на

```
extern struct commands const array[];
```